# Using the framework from one target as a pod in another target locally

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, cocoapods

I'm having trouble using a framework I wrote in other targets (the same project) using modular imports. I'm using Cocoapods. I'm getting **Could not build module:** errors while trying to import the module using modular imports (@import CMPComapiFoundation;). I attach a link to the [repo](https://github.com/comapi/comapi-sdk-ios-objc) for more information.

I did try both local (:path =>) and remote (:git =>) ways of pulling the SDK in Podfile, none of which seems to work. It's worth noting that if added via Cocoapods in a separate project, the code compiles and the SDK can be imported.

SDK's .podspec file:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             =  'CMPComapiFoundation'
  s.version          =  '1.2.2'
  s.license          =  'MIT'
  s.summary          =  'Foundation library for connecting to and consuming COMAPI services'
  s.description      = <<-DESC
# iOS SDK for Comapi
Client to connect your iOS application with [Comapi](http://comapi.com/) services and add it as a channel to our cloud messaging platform. Written in Objective-C.
For more information about the integration please visit [the website](http://docs.comapi.com/reference#one-sdk-ios).
                        DESC
  s.homepage         = 'https://github.com/comapi/comapi-sdk-ios-objc'
  s.author           = { 'Comapi' => 'support@comapi.com' }
  s.source           =  { :git => 'https://github.com/comapi/comapi-sdk-ios-objc.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }
  s.social_media_url = 'https://twitter.com/comapimessaging'

  s.ios.deployment_target = '10.0'
  s.requires_arc        = true
  s.source_files        = 'Sources/**/*.{h,m}'
  s.resources           = []

  s.dependency 'SocketRocket'

end
```

And here's the Podfile I'm using for the entire project:

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

def shared
  pod 'CMPComapiFoundation', :path => '/Users/dominik.kowalski/Documents/comapi-sdk-ios-objc'
  pod 'JWT'
end

target 'CMPComapiFoundation' do
  pod 'SocketRocket'
end

target 'CMPComapiFoundationTests' do
  shared
end

target 'ComapiFoundationSample' do
  shared
end

target 'ComapiFoundationSample-Swift' do
  shared
  pod 'SnapKit'
end
```

I expect the test and sample targets to import the modules and compile the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I managed to fix it myself. Some header files were missing Target membership, but Xcode gave me misleading hints.